# Problem with scraping data from website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to take a movie rating from the website Letterboxd. I have used code like this on other websites and it has worked, but it is not getting the info I want off of this website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://letterboxd.com/film/avengers-endgame/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
final = soup.find("section", attrs={"class":"section ratings-histogram- 
chart"})
print(final)
```

This prints nothing, but there is a tag in the website for this class and the info I want is under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this, is that the website loads most of the content asynchronously, so you'll have to look at the http requests it sends to the server in order to load the page content after loading the page layout. You can find them in "network" section in the browser (F12 key).
For instance, one of the apis they use to load the rating is this one:

https://letterboxd.com/csi/film/avengers-endgame/rating-histogram/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weighted average from another tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://letterboxd.com/film/avengers-endgame/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('[name="twitter:data2"]')['content'])
```

Text of all histogram

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://letterboxd.com/csi/film/avengers-endgame/rating-histogram/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
ratings = [item['title'].replace('\xa0',' ') for item in soup.select('.tooltip')]
print(ratings)
```